Can a spiv be a female? If not, what is the female equivalent of it?
From https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spiv:

noun
ˈspiv 
1 British : a man who lives by his wits without regular employment
2 British : SLACKER sense 1
spivvy  ˈspi-vē   adjective British

Can a spiv be a female? If not, what is the female equivalent of it?

The spiv was typically male, though Wikipedia does mention a song about a 'lady spiv'.

Can you be more specific? Spiv is often associated with men selling goods on the black market, especially in World War Two, and has become a specific stereotype of dress (flashy) and behavior, although the term can be used more widely. There are different ways a woman can make money without regular employment. So time period, employment, dress, manner, social class, etc, would all come into it.

@KateBunting, interesting...  I've never heard of spiv, but spiff is a term in sales for extra (often unearned) income from a sale, such as adding insurance to a sale of an appliance. Could there be an etymological relationship?

@DrMoishePippik - The Wikipedia article I linked to says that the OED mentions spiff as a possible derivation for the word. You don't hear spiv much nowadays except in the historical context; they were mainly active during and after WW2 when rationing was in force.

From the comments:

typically male, though Wikipedia does mention a song about a 'lady spiv'.
– Kate Bunting

And there seems to be no female equivalent for spiv.
